# Memory issues in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, knn, r-caret

I am trying to train a k-NN model with a training set which include 350k observations and 3 features (all three are categorical with 40, 50 & 100 levels). I am using knnreg from the caret package since my target vector is continuous.

My machine is pretty weak and has 4GBs of RAM. I also tried other algorithms with the same dataset and I had similar errors.

I am non the less suprised that the error pops out when I run the predict function. Here in the example I am running only 1 observation:

```
> fit <- knnreg(Sales ~ City + Store + Week, data=train, k = 2)
> predict(fit,  newdata=cv[1,])
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 452.9 Mb
```

1. Why does the error pops out when I run the predict function (and not knnreg)?
2. Is there a way to go around this?

Comment: It would be interesting to see whether the error also happens if you run `gc()` between those two commands. You could also try `debug(predict.knnreg)` in order to see what is causing the problem.

Comment: `knnreg` doesn't do much more than store the data. The `predict` function, in this case, does all the actual work.